# iMac 18,2 Audio NOT Functioning after Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Update

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, mac

So basically, I installed Ubuntu Linux 22.04.3 LTS on my iMac 2017 21.5inch Retina 4K and everything except the sound was working smoothly, I found the drivers need to make the sound work and after compiling and running these drivers: https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro everything was working smoothly, I installed all of my favorite apps and etc. then I also inside Flathub there was an option to update Ubuntu, I did it and it updated, I got into the desktop fine and noticed, sound doesn't work anymore and there is no Performance mode on Power Settings. In the log, the main audio files that got updated are:

```
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
pulseaudio-utils
pulseaudio
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-utis:amd64
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64
alsa-base 
alsa-topology-conf 
alsa-utils
gstreamer1.0-alsa
alsa
alsa-base:amd64
alsa-ucm-conf:amd64
gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64
alsa-utils:amd64
alsa-topology-conf:amd64
alsa-ucm-conf:amd64
```

For now the power problems aren't going to hurt me, plus I think I can figure that out, but sound drivers on linux are just a monster to me and I really need help.

This is the output of the installation of the Mac Audio Drivers:

```
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cs8409.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_ca0132.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cmedia.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda_i2c.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_component.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_cs_dsp_ctl.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_analog.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_conexant.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/ca0132_regs.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_generic.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_via.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_local.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_jack.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_codec.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_sysfs.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_proc.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel_trace.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cs8409-tables.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda_spi.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hp_x360_helper.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_tegra.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller_trace.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_ca0110.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/Kconfig
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_si3054.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_eld.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/Makefile
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_bind.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_jack.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_hwdep.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_beep.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/ideapad_s740_helper.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_sigmatel.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_cs_dsp_ctl.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/thinkpad_helper.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_hdmi.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cs8409.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_beep.h
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cirrus.c
linux-source-6.2.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_generic.h
Kernel version later than implemented version - there may be build problems
patching file patch_cs8409.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1444 (offset 174 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1453 (offset 174 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1482 (offset 174 lines).
patching file patch_cs8409.h
Hunk #2 succeeded at 303 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 330 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 366 (offset 1 line).
patching file patch_cirrus_apple.h
make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-1019-gcp/build CFLAGS_MODULE="-DAPPLE_PINSENSE_FIXUP -DAPPLE_CODECS -DCONFIG_SND_HDA_RECONFIG=1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function" M=/home/matheussantana/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-1019-gcp/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-1019-gcp/build'
make: *** [Makefile:16: all] Error 2
```

Please help me.

Sincerely,
AridCake

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that PulseAudio for some reason was corrupt, in order to fix that, you first need to purge Alsa and PulseAudio: `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`

Then you need to reinstall it:
`sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`

Reload Alsa and Restart the system:

`sudo alsa force-reload`

`reboot`

After that you must reinstall your drivers, the Mac sound drivers are available here: https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro

Sincerely, AridCake